# Does Syria have a law that states fleeing from the country is illegal?

Tags: criminal-law, refugee-law

I was reading this [interesting question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/8962/9674) at Expats SE. It states:

> I am a Syrian refugee who escaped the war! In my country I am considered an outlaw for doing this.

So, this makes me curious. Does the Syrian government forbid citizens from fleeing the country?

I've tried googling this, but there are so many irrelevant results, and my Google-fu belt is only yellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about law in Syria is virtually impossible to find, but there is some evidence to support the claim. [This article](http://www.refworld.org/docid/532022d84.html) notes that exit stamps are required from the Damascus airport, that men between 18 and 24 are not allowed to travel without government permission. Information from [US State Dept.](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/syria.html) indicates that "Syria charges a departure tax at its land and sea borders for all visitors except those on diplomatic passports and children under the age of 11". [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_in_Syria) cites two articles indicating that Syria requires exit visa, based on "How Syria controls its dissidents - Banning travel". *The Economist*. 30 September 2010 and Ghadry, Farid N. (Winter 2005). "Syrian Reform: What Lies Beneath". *The Middle East Quarterly*. The [Syrian Constitution](http://www.voltairenet.org/article173033.html) allows for restricting exit in Article 38(3):

> Every citizen shall have the right to move in or leave the territory
>   of the state, *unless prevented by a decision from the competent court
>   or the public prosecution office or in accordance with the laws of
>   public health and safety*

There are individual travel bans. [Louay Hussein](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-32479269), who opposes the current regime, had to escape without permission. So the individual in question may have also said something negative about the government.